# Online tool for testing freemarker templates (front-end)?

Tags: freemarker

After searching here, there (Google,...) and everywhere and not finding anything even close I decided to post my question here.

**Is there any (online) tool to test (simple(r)) Freemarker templates so as front-end developer I could use it without needing some large (resource hungry and slow) IDE and server (Tomcat) just to see HTML/CSS/JS generated at the end?**

For example:

1. define back-end data (strings, arrays, objects,...),
2. write freemarker logic (syntax checked automatically),
3. run and see final results

Or everybody just loves deployment (or buys JRebel...)?

Comment: You don't have to restart the application to test FreeMarker template changes, as FreeMarker re-loads them automatically, assuming its `template_update_delay` setting is set to a low enough value.

Comment: This worked very good for me. Still I think it would be nice to have some online tool (or for example if existing tools would have freemarker support). Thank you @ddekany

Comment: Yeah, that would be helpful for learning the FreeMarker language too... Or just to quickly try some language features you are not sure about.

Comment: Closed, but there is a tool:  http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/

Comment: @mmindenhall - thanks, seem pretty cool. Shall test it soon.